# I am unable to save and retrieve image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdocumentdirectory, nsdocumentdirectory-ios8

I am unable to save and retrieve image in iOS. I am getting nil image  trough this code:

```
-(NSString *)saveImageDataWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *photoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.png",
                           (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:getImagePath])
    {
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [data1 writeToFile:getImagePath atomically:YES];
    }
    return photoName;
}
-(UIImage *)GetImageFromPath:(NSString *)ImageName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ImageName];
    UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    return thumbNail;
}
```

Why I am getting nil image?

Please help me.

Comment: What does "I am unable" mean? You wrote some code - does it fail? Could you err-msgs? Also pls. reformat the code to make it easier to read the q.

Comment: I've edited your question to fix the formatting, but you need to include a lot more detail to allow others to help you. Have a look at "[*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for some tips.

Comment: sorry, I am new to here. Actually I was asking that is this code  okay? I can not get image from image path     UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath]; , getting nil image . I don`t know at where i m lacking .

Comment: Try debugging it.  Use breakpoints and see what the values are for things like `documentsDirectory` and `getImagePath`.  Look in the app's sandbox to see if there's really a file at the location you're trying to read.

Comment: documentDirectory :"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3F4B4215-11EB-4269-BA65-97DCC32ACAF6/Library/Documentation " and getImagePath :"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3F4B4215-11EB-4269-BA65-97DCC32ACAF6/Library/Documentation/1442405926.png"
get while i am saving image and getImagePath:"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3F4B4215-11EB-4269-BA65-97DCC32ACAF6/Library/Documentation/1442400637.png" get while retrieving image but initWithContentsOfFile: returns nil image.

Comment: replace `NSDocumentationDirectory` with `NSDocumentDirectory` in `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` function. i hope you got my point.

Comment: I replace It and its working!! superb !! :) thank you so much @DipenPanchasara. Thanks everyone  :)

Comment: @Meera you are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(NSString *)saveImageDataWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *photoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.png",
                           (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:photoName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:getImagePath])
    {
        NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [data1 writeToFile:getImagePath atomically:YES];
    }
    return photoName;
}
-(UIImage *)GetImageFromPath:(NSString *)ImageName
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory ,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ImageName];
    UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:getImagePath];
    return thumbNail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like typo in your directory name. Please replace `NSDocumentationDirectory` with `NSDocumentationDirectory` and it should work.

Comment: Yeah you are right , i got idea from @DipenPanchasara , thanks  for reply :).