# unable to form NSData using UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsdata

I have an `UIImage` and I want to make `NSData` from it and then save to a filie.

The problem is that I am able to make `UIImage` but when pass it to make `NSData` I am getting `nil` value. I tried both `UIImagePNGRepresentation` and `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`

Here is my code with detailed debuging:

```
UIImage *img  = [self.mImagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);  //nil
NSData *imgData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 50); //nil  i tried chaning 50 to 0.5 it also not working
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

Here is the image which shows I am getting UIImage but unable to form `NSData`:

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

> I am getting image from UIImagePicker and adding it in Array:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

if (!self.mImagesArray)
    self.mImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.mImagesArray addObject:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];

}
```

Comment: What about `imgData2`?

Comment: can you print the result  -->whats your [self.mImagesArray objectAtIndex:index]; contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try this one.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
```

Comment: @RahulMishra check the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs [UIImagePNGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation)

> Return Value
>   A data object containing the PNG data, or nil if there was a problem generating the data. This function may return nil if the image has no data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported bitmap format.

---

You have `UIImage` but that doesn't guarantee that it has data, e.g.

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] init];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

In this case you have the non `nil` `UIImage` object but it doesn't contain any data thus it will return `nil` `NSData`

Comment: How can I resolve this issue..but I am getting UIImage correctly ..I am choosing it from Image Picker

Comment: Can you post code how are you creating images and then adding in your array?

Comment: Seems perfect, I guess you should display this image in any image view to see if it's displaying or not

Answer (score 0):

This line works for me.

```
UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oval.png"];//[self.mImagesArray objectAtIndex:index];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
```

So, you image has problem.

**UIImagePNGRepresentation** may return nil if image has no CGImageRef or invalid bitmap format

please check

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all check your index at which index you are not getting image or getting nil. Because every time of picking image you are allocating memory to array. so first of all  allocate array in view Did Load or View Will Appear as per need. and try to debug your code by considering this point.

Hope it will help you !!

Comment: HI @meera I have already allocated the array and I am getting Image objects in array as well. But don't know why I am getting this nil value

Comment: Actually what you want to do , as per requirement i can suggest u .

Comment: I have a scenario in which user can upload five images...and then he can add or remove images .. number of images is restricted to five i have to design this scenario

Comment: Okay, Do one thing try to store your image in document directory and use this image to show. it will work. to save image refer [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606971/i-am-unable-to-save-and-retrieve-image-in-ios/33206125#33206125)